# What does >>> do in python

Tags: python

I feel that this could be very obvious, however, I keep seeing `>>>` at the start of lines of code in python and I was unsure about its purpose. So does it do anything special and does it have a name?

Comment: can you post the code? it's probably a merge conflict

Comment: It's probably the interpreter...

Comment: Please read more the [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) section.

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question could be turned into a good question according to the How To Ask guidelines that have already been linked in other comments. One of the main parts of improving the question would be to provide the actual example, and your research in attempting to solve the issue. Also, any attempts to run the code and error messages that you are encountering would be helpful. Galen's answer is probably correct for your situation, but if you are seeing them under any circumstances that don't involve the interpreter, we need that information to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see people's code online, you may see `>>>` before their code because they ran through it in the terminal. For example:

```
>>> print "Hello, World!"
Hello, World!
>>>
```

This is code they typed into the python terminal. That means they haven't saved their code to a file.

In the terminal, the arrows appear whenever the computer is ready to receive a new command. As long as it's still running the last entry, the arrows won't pop up. That's why, in the example above, there are no arrows before line 2, where the computer printed "Hello, World!". Then, as soon as it finished running, the terminal typed the arrows again, prompting the user to enter another command.

Comment: "terminal" -> "interactive interpreter"

Answer (score 5):

It is the primary prompt for the [interactive mode of the interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/interpreter.html#interactive-mode). It is not actually part of the language.

You would probably see this if someone copy and pasted from a terminal when using the interactive mode of the interpreter.